# How to start SavedAccessPointsWifiSettings programmatically?

Tags: android

I need to open android settings screen, where I can remove saved wifi networks. How can I do this? I've tried something like this, but it only open root settings screen.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, "SavedAccessPointsWifiSettings");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To open the wifi settings, you can use the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

P.S - Here's the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common) that has collection of Common Intents.

Comment: Thanx, but this is not the correct answer. I know, how to open wifi settings. But I need directly open "Saved networks" screen (SavedAccessPointsWifiSettings fragment) from my app to "forget" concurrent APs.

Comment: I see, AFAIK there isn't any intent that directly takes you to fragment that allows you to "forget" APs. The only `Settings` values related to wifi are `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS`, `ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS` & `ACTION_PROCESS_WIFI_EASY_CONNECT_URI`.